# Generic constraint

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to implement a generic validator in Swift. The validator simply performs some validation, i.e. email validation, and returns `true` or `false` based on whether or not the value is valid.

```swift
protocol Validator {
    associatedtype Value
    
    func validate(_ value: Value) -> Bool
}
```

I've also managed to get these validators implemented. As you can see, the `associatedValue` works like a charm.

```swift
struct EmailValidator: Validator {
    func validate(_ value: String) -> Bool {
        NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}").evaluate(with: value)
    }
}

struct RequiredValidator: Validator {
    func validate(_ value: String) -> Bool {
        !value.isEmpty
    }
}
```

But now I'd like to have a compound validator, that doesn't have to conform `Validator`, but it does need to accept any `Validator` where the `associatedValue` is the same. Below I have an example.

```
let compoundValidator = CompoundValidator<String>(EmailValidator(), RequiredValidator())
```

However, when I try to implement this idea, I run into errors such as `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Validator'` or `Cannot convert value of type 'Value' to expected argument type 'Validator.Value'` or `Protocol 'Validator' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` depending on what I try to implement. Is there a way I can achieve this compound validator using generics?

```swift
struct CompoundValidator<Value> {
    let validators: [Validator<Value>]
    
    init(_ validators: Validator<Value>...) {
        self.validators = validators
    }
    
    func validate(_ value: Value) -> Bool {
        validators.reduce(into: true) { partialResult, validator in
            partialResult = partialResult && validator.validate(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the beginning, `Validator<Value>` is invalid syntax, even if `Validator` is a protocol with associated types. Swift doesn't yet allow existential containers (protocol references) to declare generic constraints, the exception being the `where` clause.

Thus, you'll need a type eraser to be able to use any kind of generics:

```swift
struct AnyValidator<Value>: Validator {
    private let _validate: (Value) -> Bool
    
    init<V: Validator>(_ validator: V) where V.Value == Value {
        _validate = validator.validate
    }
    
    func validate(_ value: Value) -> Bool {
        _validate(value)
    }
}

extension Validator {
    func eraseToAnyValidator() -> AnyValidator<Value> {
        AnyValidator(self)
    }
}
```

, and you'll need to update the definition as such:

```swift
struct CompoundValidator<Value> {
    let validators: [AnyValidator<Value>]
    
    init(_ validators: AnyValidator<Value>...) {
        self.validators = validators
    }
```

However the above implementation requires all callers to call `.eraseToAnyValidator()`:

```swift
let compoundValidator = CompoundValidator(EmailValidator().eraseToAnyValidator(), RequiredValidator().eraseToAnyValidator())
```

If you want to decrease the burden on the caller, then you'll need do some work on the callee side:

```swift
struct CompoundValidator<Value> {
    let validators: [AnyValidator<Value>]
       
    init<V: Validator>(_ v: V) where V.Value == Value {
        validators = [v.eraseToAnyValidator()]
    }
    
    init<V1: Validator, V2: Validator>(_ v1: V1, _ v2: V2) where V1.Value == Value, V2.Value == Value {
        validators = [v1.eraseToAnyValidator(), v2.eraseToAnyValidator()]
    }
    
    init<V1: Validator, V2: Validator, V3: Validator>(_ v1: V1, _ v2: V2, _ v3: V3) where V1.Value == Value, V2.Value == Value, V3.Value == Value {
        validators = [v1.eraseToAnyValidator(), v2.eraseToAnyValidator(), v3.eraseToAnyValidator()]
    }
```

, basically you'll need to add as many initializers as many arguments you'll want to pass through the codebase. This enables you to call the initializer in the simple form:

```swift
let compoundValidator = CompoundValidator(EmailValidator(), RequiredValidator())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `AnyValidator` type, that is a concrete type. This way you can use it to specify the generic type arguments.

```
struct AnyValidator<Value>: Validator {
    private let validateFunc: (Value) -> Bool
    
    init<T: Validator>(_ validator: T) where T.Value == Value {
        validateFunc = validator.validate
    }
    
    func validate(_ value: Value) -> Bool {
        validateFunc(value)
    }
}

extension Validator {
    func eraseToAnyValidator() -> AnyValidator<Value> {
        .init(self)
    }
}

struct CompoundValidator<Value> {
    let validators: [AnyValidator<Value>]
    
    init(_ validators: AnyValidator<Value>...) {
        self.validators = validators
    }
    
    func validate(_ value: Value) -> Bool {
        validators.reduce(into: true) { partialResult, validator in
            partialResult = partialResult && validator.validate(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
CompoundValidator(
    EmailValidator().eraseToAnyValidator(),
    RequiredValidator().eraseToAnyValidator())
```

You might want to provide convenience initialisers for few numbers of validators:

```
init<V1, V2>(_ v1: V1, _ v2: V2) where V1: Validator, V2: Validator, V1.Value == Value, V2.Value == Value {
    self.init(v1.eraseToAnyValidator(), v2.eraseToAnyValidator())
}
init<V1, V2, V3>(_ v1: V1, _ v2: V2, _ v3: V3) where V1: Validator, V2: Validator, V3: Validator, V1.Value == Value, V2.Value == Value, V3.Value == Value {
    self.init(v1.eraseToAnyValidator(), v2.eraseToAnyValidator(), v3.eraseToAnyValidator())
}
```

which allows you to omit `.eraseToAnyValidator()`.

This is similar to how Combine's [`Publisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher) type has a [`merge`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/merge(with:_:)) operator that accepts up to *eight* arguments, just to allow you to merge different types of `Publisher`s without saying `eraseToAnyPublisher`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your answer is practically the same as Cristik's one, which came in quicker, hence my acceptance of that answer. Nevertheless, thanks for your input and effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct CompoundValidator<Value, T: Validator> where T.Value == Value {
    let validators: [T]

    init(_ validators: T...) {
        self.validators = validators
    }

    func validate(_ value: Value) -> Bool {
        validators.reduce(into: true) { partialResult, validator in
            partialResult = partialResult && validator.validate(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just got that code too haha. Unfortunately `let emailFieldValidator = CompoundValidator(EmailValidator(), RequiredValidator())` does not work now. `Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'T' ('EmailValidator' vs. 'RequiredValidator')` Any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: This requires all validator be of the same type, which is not very helpful for the context of the question.